# Perl split function - use repeating characters as delimiter

Tags: regex, perl

I want to split a string using repeating letters as delimiter, for example,
`"123aaaa23a3"` should be split as `('123', '23a3')` while `"123abc4"` should be left unchanged.
So I tried this:

```
@s = split /([[:alpha:]])\1+/, '123aaaa23a3';
```

But this returns `'123', 'a', '23a3'`, which is not what I wanted. Now I know that this is because the last `'a'` in `'aaaa'` is captured by the parantheses and thus preserved by `split()`. But anyway, I can't add something like `?:` since `[[:alpha:]]` must be captured for back reference.
How can I resolve this situation?

Comment: I don't think you can modify the regex to avoid having a capturing group, but you *can* just throw away all of the odd-numbered elements of the list returned by `split`

Comment: If the regex has capture groups, the returned list contains the matched/grouped substrings as well. You could use an alternative: `my $str = '123aaaa23a3' =~ s/([[:alpha:]])\1+/~~/r; my @s = split /~~/, $str;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, its an interesting one. My first thought would be - your delimiter will always be odd numbers, so you can just discard any odd numbered array elements.

Something like this perhaps?:

```
my %s = (split (/([[:alpha:]])\1+/, '123aaaa23a3'), '' );
print Dumper \%s;
```

This'll give you:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '23a3' => '',
          '123' => 'a'
        };
```

So you can extract your pattern via `keys`.

Unfortunately my second approach of 'selecting out' the pattern matches via `%+` doesn't help particularly (split doesn't populate the regex stuff).

But something like this:

```
my @delims ='123aaaa23a3' =~ m/(?<delim>[[:alpha:]])\g{delim}+/g; 
print Dumper \%+;
```

By using a named capture, we identify that `a` is from the capture group. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be populated when you do this via `split` - which might lead to a two-pass approach.

This is the closest I got:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = '123aaaa23a3';

#build a regex out of '2-or-more' characters. 
my $regex = join ( "|", map { $_."{2,}"} $str =~ m/([[:alpha:]])\1+/g);
#make the regex non-capturing
$regex = qr/(?:$regex)/;
print "Using: $regex\n";

#split on the regex
my @s  = split m/$regex/, $str;

print Dumper \@s;
```

We first process the string to extract "2-or-more" character patterns, to set as our delmiters. Then we assemble a regex out of them, using non-capturing, so we can split.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to use your original `split` call and throw away every other value. Conveniently, `List::Util::pairkeys` is a function that keeps the first of every pair of values in its input list:

```
use List::Util 1.29 qw( pairkeys );

my @vals = pairkeys split /([[:alpha:]])\1+/, '123aaaa23a3';
```

Gives

```
Odd number of elements in pairkeys at (eval 6) line 1.
[ '123', '23a3' ]
```

That warning comes from the fact that `pairkeys` wants an even-sized list. We can solve that by adding one more value at the end:

```
my @vals = pairkeys split( /([[:alpha:]])\1+/, '123aaaa23a3' ), undef;
```

Alternatively, and maybe a little neater, is to add that extra value at the start of the list and use `pairvalues` instead:

```
use List::Util 1.29 qw( pairvalues );

my @vals = pairvalues undef, split /([[:alpha:]])\1+/, '123aaaa23a3';
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'split' can be made to work directly by using the delayed execution assertion (aka postponed regular subexpression), `(??{ code })`, in the regular expression:

```
@s = split /[[:alpha:]](??{"$&+"})/, '123aaaa23a3';
```

`(??{ code })` is documented on the 'perlre' manual page.

Note that, according to the 'perlvar' manual page, the use of `$&` anywhere in a program imposes a considerable performance penalty on all regular expression matches.  I've never found this to be a problem, but YMMV.