# Split string where the character changes

Tags: regex, perl

I want to create an array that splits whenever a character stops repeating. My current code is:

```
my $str = "1233345abcdde";
print "$_," for split /(?<=(.))(?!\1)/, $str;
```

This returns: `1,1,2,2,333,3,4,4,5,5,a,a,b,b,c,c,dd,d,e,e,`

However, what I really want is:
`1,2,333,4,5,a,b,c,dd,e,`, i.e. without the duplicate chars.

What's wrong? I suspect the problem has to do with the nature of lookarounds, but I can't pin it down ...

Comment: Thank you all for sharing your insights. I decided to use `my @matches; push @matches, $1 while $str =~ /((.)\2*)/g;` for this [CodeGolf challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58523/write-two-programs-that-compresses-and-decompresses-data/58543#58543), amongst the 6 or so different options provided by you here. I think this is the most readable and elegant solution. I also benchmarked the different approaches for fun, but found no significant performance differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the problem is because you're using capture groups in `split` - which returns the "capture" along with the "split".

```
use Data::Dumper;
my @stuff = split /(=)/, "this=that";
print Dumper \@stuff;
```

Gives:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'this',
          '=',
          'that'
        ];
```

Unfortunately it's not easy to 'fix' - best I could come up with is skip the odd numbered elements:

```
my %stuff =  split /(?<=(.))(?!\1)/, $str;
print Dumper \%stuff;
```

(That won't preserve ordering though, because hashes don't).

But you can:

```
print join (",", sort keys %stuff);
```

Or perhaps:

```
my $str = "1233345abcdde";
my @stuff =  split /(?<=(.))(?!\1)/, $str;
print join ( ",", @stuff[grep { not $_ & 1 } 0..$#stuff] ),"\n";
```

Comment: Yes, my bad. I changed it back to using an intermediary hash variable.

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want, but you almost certainly shouldn’t use it:

```
split /(??{ (substr $_, (pos)-1, 1) eq (substr $_, pos, 1) ? '(?!)' : '' })/, $str
```

Comment: Interestingly, split checks at position zero, but ignores the result.

Comment: It always ignores zero-width matches at the start of the string. Consider `split /b*/, 'abba'` vs `split /b*/, 'abba', -1`. The pattern has a zero-width match at both ends of the string but there is no way to get the leading one out of `split`, only the trailing one.

Comment: You missed my point. It's not the fact that it doesn't split at pos 0 that's interesting, it's that split checks for a match at pos 0 knowing that it won't split at pos 0.

Comment: It doesn’t necessarily know that. Consider `split /b*/, 'ba'`. There is a width-1 separator at the start of the string, which `split` must skip. But the same pattern will have a zero-width match at the start of a string that starts with something else. So whether a pattern will produce zero-width matches may depend on the string. Therefore the only circumstance in which `split` can know that it won’t split at pos 0 is if it’s given a pattern that can *only* ever produce zero-width matches; in any other case, `split` has to check at pos 0. That may be too narrow a special case to be worthwhile.

Comment: Re "is if it’s given a pattern that can only ever produce zero-width matches", oh, right. (`perl -E'say for split /[ab]/, "abc";'` splits at 0.)

Answer (score 1):

When the `split` regexp includes a capture group, the return list also includes the values from these captures. You'll have to filter them out somehow.

You want the same as the answer:

[Perl split function - use repeating characters as delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686837/perl-split-function-use-repeating-characters-as-delimiter/32693008#32693008)

Comment: Putting `pairkeys` from `List::Util` in front of my `split` did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you use captures, they text they capture gets returned too. You could filter out these extra values.

```
my $i; my @matches = grep { ++$i % 2 } split /(?<=(.))(?!\1)/s, $str;
```

```
use List::Util qw( pairkeys );  # 1.29+
my @matches = pairkeys split /(?<=(.))(?!\1)/s, $str;
```

It's simpler to use a regex match.

```
my @matches; push @matches, $1 while $str =~ /((.)\2*)/sg;
```

```
my $i; my @matches = grep { ++$i % 2 } $str =~ /((.)\2*)/sg;
```

```
use List::Util qw( pairkeys );  # 1.29+
my @matches = pairkeys $str =~ /((.)\2*)/sg;
```

Comment: Grep version works great, but the regex versions return something like `[1,2,3,3,3,2,1]` instead of the expected `[1,2,333,2,1]`

Comment: Oops, suppose to be `\2` instead of `\1`. Fixed.

Comment: Ah.. I should've realized the outer parentheses would be `\1` and inner `\2`. Thanks for adding greatly to my arsenal!

Comment: Captures are numbered based on the order of their opening paren.